Is there a compact code in R for fully factorial interactions
I am trying to compare R and Stata versions of models with interactions.
In Stata the ## factor variable operator allows full-factorial interactions.
So for, say, a logistic regression model with "a" as the binary dependent variable and independent variables b (continuous) k, l, m (categorical), the following syntax ("c." is a unary operator to specify  continuous  and "i." is a unary operator to specify indicators)
logit a c.b##(i.k i.l i.m) 

will expand to yield the full factorial interaction, which is very useful in a complex model with a large variable list.
I have reviewed "The R book" by Crawley and undertook a Google search with a varied syntax searches but these did not yield exactly what I needed. Apologies if I have missed the obvious.

Maybe  glm(a ~ b*(k + l + m), family=binomial, data=mydata)

I was thinking maybe k*l*m

Or b * (k + l + m) ^ 2. These guesses show that you can't expect others to know what the stata code does exactly and what you consider "fully factorial interactions". The code provided by @IRTFM expands to all possible interactions and includes the main effects, i.e. k * l * m expands to k + l + m + k:l +k:m + l:m + k:l:m. Read help("formula").

According to the stata manual (25.2.11 Parentheses binding), regress y sex##(group c.age c.age#c.age) is equivalent to regress y i.sex i.group sex#group age sex#c.age c.age#c.age sex#c.age#c.age, which in R equates to y ~ sex*group + sex*age + sex*age*age, or compactly: y ~ sex*(group + age + age:age)

@Edward Or even more, y ~ sex*(group + age^2).

Thank you for all the replies and I apologize for not providing the Stata  "meaning"  of fully factorial interaction. This would expand  to   logit a  b k l m bk  bl bm, as noted by @Edward and the  suggestion of b(k+l+m) is just that. I appreciate the other comments.  As also noted,  klm, expanding to all interactions and main effects, does not correspond with the Stata meaning of fully factorial interaction.
